# Laravel Controller Delegation

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-routing

Trying to keep my Laravel project organized here, while letting it grow.

Currently I use:

```
Route::controller('/admin', 'AdminController');
```

...in order to allow the controller to service general admin pages. This is working fine, however I'd like to delegate specific subqueries to other controllers for cleanliness reasons.

For example, I'd like */admin/dashboard* to resolve to **AdminController@getDashboard**. I'd also like */admin/gallery/* to resolve to **AdminGalleryController@getIndex**, and */admin/foo/bar* to resolve to **AdminFooController@getBar**.

Is there a simple way to slowly expand functionality like this?

---

We've migrated to Laravel 5 and 5.1, and this still remains a good way to do things. If you aren't using route groups in Laravel, then you aren't doing Laravel right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define those others as controller routes as well. Just do it *before* `Route::controller('admin')` because Laravel searches the registered routes in the other you define them. Since `/admin/gallery` would match `Route::controller('admin')` as well as `Route::controller('admin/gallery')` latter has to be defined first:

```
Route::controller('admin/gallery', 'AdminGalleryController');
Route::controller('admin/foo', 'AdminFooController');
Route::controller('admin', 'AdminController');
```

---

Instead of writing `admin` every time a route group might be a nice improvement as well:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function(){
    Route::controller('gallery', 'AdminGalleryController');
    Route::controller('foo', 'AdminFooController');
    Route::controller('/', 'AdminController');
});
```

Comment: You got sniped by a few mins, but I'm awarding the answer for the elegance it provides.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Simply declare your "exception" routes before your main controller route.

```
Route::get('/admin/gallery','AdminGalleryContoller@getIndex');
Route::get('/admin/dashboard','AdminController@getDasboard');
Route::controller('/admin','AdminController');
```

Comment: That's not true. It would only override the previous route if it had the same URI and method. However `Route::controller('admin')` will just grab any request starting with `admin`. The get routes would need to be defined **before** the controller route.

Comment: You are of course correct, it's been a long day. Edited my answer.